# crash from google play

Tags: android, crash

on last day i pushed my app on Google play , and i get this crash from some user on Google play developer console

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{alhazmy.Balot_Calculator/alhazmy.Balot_Calculator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2685)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:126)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2038)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1010)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:902)
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:855)
at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.setContentView(ActionBarSherlock.java:671)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:272)
at alhazmy.Balot_Calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2633)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:174)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$attr
... 29 more
```

can any one help me how i can solve this Crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that you missing the SherlockActionbar library in your package

Might be an issue cause by https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55304 ?

For all projects (app and library):

1. Right click the project, and choose Properties
2. Go to Java Build Path-Order and Export.
3. Tick 'Android Private Libraries'